# How to read spaces in FOR loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I'm new here. I am trying to write a de-bloat script for Android.
Below is my code :-

```
#/system/bin/sh
clear
list=$(cat <<'EOF'
Beauty\ Plus
blackmart
Cam\ Scanner
Tencent
EOF
)

for f in $(echo "$list");
do
if [ -e /sdcard/$f* ];
    then
    rm -rf /sdcard/$f*
    echo -e "Deleted /sdcard/$f*."
else
    echo -e "/sdcard/$f* not found."
fi
done
```

Now here is the issue, it reads both the occurrences with space as different entries. I have made sure that I use echo with variables enclosed in quotes.

If I just try

```
echo "$list"
```

Then, it gives the desired output. I have also tried using the

```
echo "$list" | while read f
do
echo $f
done
```

But, it also gives the same output.
Please help me with this.
The output should be like this :-

```
Beauty\ Circle
Cam\ Scanner
```

so that I write my further code as :-

```
for f in $(echo "list");
do
rm -rf /sdcard/$f
echo -e "Removed \/sdcard\/$f"
done
```

Thank you.

P.S: I don't want to use

```
rm -rf /sdcard/$f*
```

Comment: That question has an emphasis on storing entire command lines, not just arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to run the script with `/bin/sh` (which might be a shell that does not support arrays), you need to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  rm -rf /sdcard/"$f"
  printf 'Removed /sdcard/%s\n' "$f"
done <<EOF
Beauty Plus
blackmart
Cam Scanner
Tencent
EOF
```

If you can use `#!/bin/bash`, then you can use a `for` loop to iterate over an array instead of a regular parameter.

```
list=( "Beauty Plus"
blackmart
"Cam Scanner"
Tencent
)
for f in "${list[@]}"; do
  rm -rf /sdcard/"$f"
  printf 'Removed /sdcard/%s\n' "$f"
done
```